# Why my Circular Singly Linked List Java code not working? It says that Node is null can't put data on it

Tags: java, nodes, singly-linked-list, circular-list

For the meantime, I'm trying to figure out the basics of how Circular Singly Linked List works. In this case, I'm creating a program in which, user can input from 1 to 3, the number of linked nodes. However, I'm stuck for over 5 hours and can't find a solution elsewhere on this problem. It says that I cannot assign data on my Node because it is null, but I already assigned it to a newnode.

After figuring this 1-3 node circular singly linked list. I'm planning on increasing the nodes.

The IDE says this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "data" because "DS2.prac2.head" is null
at DS2.prac2.inc(prac2.java:47)
at DS2.prac2.Start(prac2.java:34)
at DS2.prac2.main(prac2.java:104)
```

My code:

````
package DS2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prac2{

    
    static class Node {  
        int data;  
        Node next;  
      
      
    }
  
   
    static Node head;  
    static Node tail;  
    static Node current;  
    public static int num;

    public prac2(){


        num=0;
    }


 
    static void Start(int n){ //Starts the program

   
    
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){ //A loop to create nodes
        inc();
    }

    }

    static void inc(){  //the method for each nodes created

        Node newnode = new Node();
        newnode.data=num;num++;
        newnode.next=head;
        
        if(num==1){
            newnode=null;
            head.data=num;num++;
            head.next=head;
            

        }

        else if(num==2){
       
        tail=newnode;
        head.next=tail;

        }
        else{
         
            tail.next=newnode;
            tail=newnode;

        }



    }

    static void Display(){ //For Displaying the Circular List
    int temp1=0;
    current=head;

    do{
    if(current==head)  //If current passed head twice it means that it passed through all the nodes
        temp1++;

    System.out.println(current.data);
    current=current.next;


    }
    while(temp1==1);

    

    }
  
   
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

      

        int M,N;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       // M=scan.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Input how many nodes (1-3): ");
        N=scan.nextInt();
       
        Start(N);

        scan.close();



        
        
    }
}```
````

Comment: perhaps step through with a debugger?

Comment: In `inc()` when `if(num==1){`, `head` is `null`.

Comment: whitespace improves readability but too much reduces it

Comment: I'd like to help you but your overuse of static just grosses me out.
The only thing that should be static is your main().
It's like I got teleported back to the 80s working on bad C code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
head.data=num;num++;
```

It is quite clear that `head` was never assigned a node reference. It is still `null`. In fact, you *did* create a node and assigned it to `newnode`, but then with `newnode=null` you cut the reference to it. Instead you should have assigned it to `head`, with `head=newnode`.

In the case the node is the first node, you should *also* initialise `tail` -- to be the *same* node as the `head` node.

Here is corrected code for `inc`:

```
static void inc() {
    Node newnode = new Node();
    newnode.data = num++;
        
    if (head == null){
        head = newnode;
    } else {
        tail.next = newnode;
    }

    tail = newnode;
    tail.next = head;
}
```

Not related, but you could get rid of `head` all together, as it can be derived from `tail`. When `tail` is `null` then you know the head is `null` too. If `tail` is not `null` you know that the head is at `tail.next`. So there really is no reason to waste memory on storing `head`. Of course, this means you will have to rewrite the display function a bit too.